# Отправка уведомлений на почту через PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Есть скрипт который мониторит место на дисках.

```
$a = "testdb"#список серверов
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicalDisk -ComputerName $a | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3} | ft -Property DeviceID,
@{Label="Имя сервера"; Expression={$a}},
@{Label="Свободное место(GB)"; Expression={[Math]::Round(($_.FreeSpace/1Gb),0)}}
```

Результат выводится в виде:

DeviceID | Имя сервера | Свободное место(GB)

Нужно настроить отправку уведомлений о размере свободного места используя PowerShell.

Как мне запихнуть результат запроса в:

```
Send-MailMessage `
-From '' `
-To '' `
-Subject "Место на дисках " `
-Body  'test'`
-BodyAsHtml `
–SmtpServer '' `
-Port  `
-Encoding 'UTF8'
```

Comment: https://mailtrap.io/blog/powershell-send-email/ как-то так можно попробовать